# Hiberate mapping and java code for a database sequence

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a sequence in the DB like this

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE abc
        INCREMENT BY 1
        START WITH 1
 ;
```

I want a method like

```
getNextVal(); //My guess is I can fire select abc.nextval from dual
```

Which returns the next value from the sequence.

How should the .hbm.xml and the code for getNextVal look like. I am new to Hibernate , I tried digging up but have not been able to find a definitive answer.

Is the way of creating sequence optimal.

Answer (score 1):

If you need sequence value to generate id, you don't have to worry about `getNextVal()` as it will be done for you based on your mapping with generated id. Some examples can be found [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/example-mappings.html). And [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier) is some info for annotations.

If you need sequence value for some other reason, you would have to do native SQL query. Something like this

```
Number val=session.createSQLQuery("select abc.nextval from dual").uniqueResult();
```

Comment: All the examples tell me that the sequence is used inside a table. How would the mapping with just the sequence look like

Comment: As I mentioned, if you don't need it for id (which is most typical use case) then you can use native SQL as I described.

Comment: I am guessing that means no mapping is required, is that correct.

Comment: It may also be possible to use formula (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-column). But I never tried that.